# Timestamp issue?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, discord.js, google-sheets-api

i have a google form and using the same spreadsheets that connected to discord bot using node.js and google api v4.

My problem is when the sender use the google form to send the data, the data is always on top of the data that is sended by the discord bot (See image attached below).

I think the timestamps might be the issue, but the timestamps format i use to input the data from discord bot is using the timestamp format same as the google forms.
Maybe anyone can help me with this issue?

Here is the picture of the problem from the spreadsheets
[image: imgsheets]

Comment: why is the arrangement of the data a problem? and what happens if you add a sorting function to the `Timestamp` column?

Comment: i'm already use the filter from A to Z and vice versa, but it is still not use because the timestamp time now sorting random thing.

here is the image when i filter the Timestamp column
https://imgur.com/a/MTogpse

Comment: How do you filter your `Timestamp` column? Have you checked your format if it is in `Date Time`?

Comment: yes, i use the Format > Number > Date Time, then i use the Filter > From A to Z and vice versa

Comment: so, what you are trying to achieve is to sort the timestamps in a chronological order, starting with the most recent entry. is this right?

Comment: yes, that is true, sorting from older data to newer data

Comment: What can I suggest is that, you `re highlight` your `Timestamp` column then  format it again to `Date Time` then filter it to A to Z, because it seems that whenever there is a new data inserted, it is formatted as a `string` or would you like an apps script instead?

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the screenshot provided, after sorting, it was noticed that one of the timestamps, `29/02/2024 16:15:35`, appeared to be aligned to the left while the rest were aligned to the right.

[image: screenshot]

This often happens when there is a `'` in the front of the value, transforming it to a text value instead of a numerical value. While sorting from Z to A, text values should appear on top of numerical values, like this.

[image: sorting]

How this may have happened is that your Discord code is capturing timestamps in the form of `'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss'`. You can rely on the `SUBSTITUTE` function to remove and replace any instance of `'`, like this `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'","")` before re-applying the sorting.